# ImageMagick fails to convert PDF files containing functional shading

Tags: shading, gif

## Question

I would like to make a GIF animation out of a series of functional shadings. But it seems ImageMagick cannot even handle one shading. Did I miss any option of ImageMagick? Or are there any alternatives?

## Story

The PGF manual proposed a beautiful shading

[image]

of which an MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\tikz\shade[shading=Mandelbrot set](0,0)rectangle(2,2);
\end{document}
```

Then I found that ImageMagick does not convert the resulting PDF properly. For instance with

```
convert -density 1440 in.pdf out.gif
```

it gives

[image]

Comment: I like that "glitchy" effect.

Comment: @Clément That is the annoying part! ImageMagick definitely knows functional shading, but it behaves like it is unwilling to deal with it.

Comment: Yes, I know! I tried other options with `gs`, with `dvi` outputs, and get the same (or even worst) results. What makes you think the problem comes from PGF and not from ImageMagick?

Comment: @Clément It would be nice if "it is PGF's fault **and** we can find other ways to generate functional shadings". In this manner, even TeX is not really necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to (problematic) optimization of external script (Ghostscript and ImageMagick)